# Cannot find 'CodingKeys' in scope, inconsistent error

Tags: swift, xcode, codable, grdb

I'm working on a GRDB data model. My problem *might* be rooted by working on beta:
Version 12.0 beta 2 (12A6163b).

I've got an intermittent error showing up in several structs. `Cannot find 'CodingKeys'` shows up on a few lines in a few struct definitions. This happens after `CodingKeys` has been accepted on several lines before or after the indicated line. See below for sample code.

I'm using a enum based on [GRDB documentation](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/README.md#records).

My data model has 13 tables and struct definitions. This error is showing up six of the struct definitions on one or two of the lines in the `Columns` enum. I cannot find any common denominator for which lines the error shows up on.

The error on the sample below, uuidCommodity is a UUID type variable, but I've also seen the error on rows with Date, String, and Int types.

Anyone else seeing this problem? Anyone have any suggestions? I filed this with Apple Feedback last night, no answers from there yet, but it is the weekend.

```
import Foundation
import GRDB

struct Accounts: Codable, Identifiable {

    var id: UUID {
        return uuidKey
    }

    // MARK: - GrandSync Properties
    var uuidKey: UUID
    var uuidUser: UUID
    var uuidFamily: UUID
    var dateCreated: Date
    var dateModified: Date? // nil if never saved
    var dateArchived: Date? // nil if never archived
    var datePost: Date? // nil if not synced to Postgres
    var myName: String

    // MARK: - Subclass Properties
    var limitCents: Int
    var uuidCommodity: UUID
    var uuidParent: UUID?


}

// MARK: - SQL Generation
extension Accounts: TableRecord, FetchableRecord, PersistableRecord {

    static let databaseTableName = "accounts"

    /// The table columns
    enum Columns {
        static let uuidKey = Column(CodingKeys.uuidKey)
        static let uuidUser = Column(CodingKeys.uuidUser)
        static let uuidFamily = Column(CodingKeys.uuidFamily)
        static let dateCreated = Column(CodingKeys.dateCreated)
        static let dateModified = Column(CodingKeys.dateModified)
        static let dateArchived = Column(CodingKeys.dateArchived)
        static let datePost = Column(CodingKeys.datePost)
        static let myName = Column(CodingKeys.myName)
        static let limitCents = Column(CodingKeys.limitCents)
        static let uuidCommodity = Column(CodingKeys.uuidCommodity)  // Error shows up on this line
        static let uuidParent = Column(CodingKeys.uuidParent)
    }
...
```

Edit: Adding an explicit CodingKeys enum made the error go away, but I still don't know why the initial error was there.

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case uuidKey, uuidUser, uuidFamily, dateCreated, dateModified, dateArchived, datePost, myName, abrv, iCommodityType
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an Xcode 12 beta error. Workaround is detailed here, https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/issues/804. Just add `Accounts.` before `CodingKeys`.